# How to use logged exception in conditional statement in Python

Tags: python

I have an SMTP email handler which logs and emails my traceback errors, this is built with a try/except block. I would like to use a conditional statement that says if an email is sent then do something else. How can this be done?

Taken from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86616/how-to-use-logged-exception-in-if-statement-in-python?noredirect=1#comment156199_86616

```
class TlsSMTPHandler(logging.handlers.SMTPHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        """
        Emit a record.

        Format the record and send it to the specified addressees.
        """
        try:
            import smtplib
            import string # for tls add this line
            try:
                from email.utils import formatdate
            except ImportError:
                formatdate = self.date_time
            port = self.mailport
            if not port:
                port = smtplib.SMTP_PORT
            smtp = smtplib.SMTP(self.mailhost, port)
            msg = self.format(record)
            msg = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\nDate: %s\r\n\r\n%s" % (
                            self.fromaddr,
                            string.join(self.toaddrs, ","),
                            self.getSubject(record),
                            formatdate(), msg)
            if self.username:
                smtp.ehlo() # for tls add this line
                smtp.starttls() # for tls add this line
                smtp.ehlo() # for tls add this line
                smtp.login(self.username, self.password)
            smtp.sendmail(self.fromaddr, self.toaddrs, msg)
            smtp.quit()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)

logger = logging.getLogger()

gm = TlsSMTPHandler(("smtp.gmail.com", 587), 'email', ['email'], 'Error found!', ('email', 'password'))
gm.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

logger.addHandler(gm)


try:
   a bunch of code that works
except:
    logger.exception("Something has gone wrong!")

        ##I would like to use an if statement after the except which says if logger.execption was executed then do something`
```

Comment: Just put your code after `logger.exception("Something has gone wrong!")`. Also do not use single `except` statements, but `except Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the statement which you want to be executed after the exception is raised and you can use else with try-except to execute a task when no exception is raised. Something like this:

```
try:
  //your code
except:
  logger.exception("Something has gone wrong!")
  // send a mail or print this log
else:
  print "all went fine..no exception"
```

Comment: This is the track that I am on, however in this `else` statement how would I write, `if exception is raised, do this...`

Answer (score 0):

This might be the way, if I got your question,

```
success_flag = False
try:
    do_send_mail_stuff()
    print "Successfully done stuff"
    success_flag = True
except smtp_exception1:
    log_exception()
    do_stuff_for_failure_case1()
except smtp_exception2:
    log_exception()
    do_stuff_for_failure_case2()
except other_exception:
    log_exception()
    print "something not right"
finally:
    if success_flag:
        print "success"
        do_success_stuff()
    else:
        do_not_success_stuff()
```

To know what exceptions sendmail can raise, read https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail

Comment: I understand the logic behind it, but what I do not understand the syntax for `if logger.exception sends email, then do this`  logger.exception is a function that prints and returns a generator, I have tried if `logger.exception ==True` but that does not work.  So I would like to keep my initial `except` but have  a `finally` after it that says `if logger.except is executed: then do this`

Comment: In that case, set a particular flag, whenever certain activity is executed successfully, and use that flag in condition checking to further operation regarding that particular operation.